# Split string by hashtag and save into array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I have a var that has a string with a series of words, some of which have hashtags, eg:

```
var words = "#hashtagged no hashtag #antoherhashtag";
```

I want to save each hashtagged word into an array, kind of like:

```
var tagslistarr = words.split(' ');
```

But I am unsure of how to get the characters surrounded by both the # and the space.

Is there a special way of doing this? Is there some ASCII characters I am meant to use to identify this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/necBY/)

```
var words = "#hashtagged no hashtag #antoherhashtag";
var tagslistarr = words.split(' ');
var arr=[];
$.each(tagslistarr,function(i,val){
    if(tagslistarr[i].indexOf('#') == 0){
      arr.push(tagslistarr[i]);  
    }
});
console.log(arr);
```

`tagslistarr = words.split(' ')` splits words with spaces to from a new array

[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loops through the each value of  `tagslistarr` array

`if(tagslistarr[i].indexOf('#') == 0)` checks is the `#` is in the beginning of the and if this condition is `true` it adds it into the `arr` array

Answer (score 23):

```
var words = "#hashtagged no hashtag #antoherhashtag";
var tagslistarr = words.match(/#\S+/g);   //["#hashtagged", "#antoherhashtag"]
```

Comment: you can get away without having the dot there, can't you? just (/#\S+/g)

Comment: +1 This answer is much more efficient the the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var tmplist = words.split(' ');
var hashlist = [];
var nonhashlist = [];
for(var w in tmplist){
    if(tmplist[ w ].indexOf('#') == 0)
        hashlist.push(tmplist[ w ]);
    else
        nonhashlist.push(tmplist[ w ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var words = "#hashtagged no hashtag #antoherhashtag";
var tagslistarr = words.match(/(^|\s)#([^ ]*)/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex is pretty simple with pure JavaScript:

```
var str = "Lorem #ipsum dolor sit #amet";
var hashArray = (str.match(/#(\w+)/g));

console.log(hashArray);
// => [ '#ipsum', '#amet' ]
console.log(Array.isArray(hashArray));
// => true
```

https://repl.it/C8GJ

If you need to handle diacritics:

```
var str = "Loröm #ipsöm dolor sit #amöt";
var hashArray = (str.match(/#([A-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+)/g));

console.log(hashArray);
// => [ '#ipsöm', '#amöt' ]
console.log(Array.isArray(hashArray));
// => true
```

https://repl.it/@ryanpcmcquen/QuickwittedParallelLemming

Comment: if using diacritics (accented letters) it only shows that word to that point - worth updating