# Extracting hashtags out of a string.

Tags: javascript, hashtag

If I had a string as such

```
var comment =  "Mmmm #yummy #donut at #CZ"
```

How can I get a list of hash tags that exist in the string variable?

I tried using JavaScript split() method but I have to keep splitting all strings created from the initial split string. 
Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268256/split-string-by-hashtag-and-save-into-array-with-jquery

Comment: You're looking for https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will do it for anything with alphabetic characters, you can extend the regexp for other characters if you want:

```
myString.match(/#[a-z]+/gi);
```

Comment: Thanks I'm new to JS, I did think it would be so simple in JS. :)

Comment: On the surface this works but if you look at the link @SLaks provided, the hash tag syntax is a bit more complicated

Comment: This doesn't capture numbers in hashtags or text after underscores. 

If you want this support use: `text.match(/#[a-z0-9_]+/g);`. 

And here's an working playground example: http://regexr.com/3gkpo

Comment: It works for the examples given - this isn't necessarily a Twitter-related question. If it is, or the hash tag syntax is more complicated than stated here, then I would agree something different may be needed. Answer is based off of the question without reading into it further.

Comment: @pbojinov the regex is excluding the last hashtag which has no space in the end. In the example, #CZ. This also includes the last hashtag  
```
 text.match(/#[a-z0-9_]+/gi)
```

Comment: This won't work with other alphabets unfortunately

Rather use `.split(/[\s\n\r]/gmi).filter(v=> v.startsWith('#'))`

Answer (score 18):

Just use a regular expression to find occurences of a hash followed by non-whitespace characters.

```
"Mmmm #yummy #donut at #CZ".match(/#\w+/g)
// evaluates to ["#yummy", "#donut", "#CZ"]
```

Answer (score 12):

Do you care about Unicode or non-English hashtags?

```
"Mmmm #yummy #donut at #CZ #中文 #.dou #。#？#♥️ #にほ".match(/#[\p{L}]+/ugi)
=> (5) ["#yummy", "#donut", "#CZ", "#中文", "#にほ"]
```

As explained by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35112226/515585

> `\p{L}` matches unicode characters
>
> `u` the PCRE_UTF8 modifier, this modifier turns on additional
>   functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl.

Comment: #hash-tags, #sea_lion not working

Answer (score 6):

if you care about readability:

```
yourText.split(' ').filter(v=> v.startsWith('#'))
```

will return `["#yummy", "#donut", "#CZ"]`

Comment: this is awesome! very easy and does whats needed!

Comment: this will create problem if the hash tag is the last word of a line and another line is there.

Comment: I think this is not enough as it won't work with return carriages

`.split(/[\s\n\r]/gmi).filter(v=> v.startsWith('#'))` will do better I guess and will also work with all languages

Answer (score 2):

Here is another very simple regex which will allow using emojis and numbers in hashtags as well as not using any white space to have them split. Most of the time this should be more than sufficent:

```
"Mmmm #yummy #donut at #CZ#efrefg #:) #cool#r234#FEGERGR#fegergr".match(/#[^\s#]*/gmi);
// => ["#yummy", "#donut", "#CZ", "#efrefg", "#:)", "#cool", "#r234", "#FEGERGR", "#fegergr"]
```

---

There is a little downside though: This regex will add punctuation to the end of hashtags, e.g.:

```
"Mmmm #yummy.#donut#cool#r234#FEGERGR;#fegergr".match(/#[^\s#]*/gmi);
// => ["#yummy.", "#donut", "#cool", "#r234", "#FEGERGR;", "#fegergr"]
```

---

But you can extend the regex yourself to the characters (punctuation) that you want to omit though, like this:

```
"Mmmm #yummy.#donut#cool#r234#FEGERGR;#fegergr".match(/#[^\s#\.\;]*/gmi);
// => ["#yummy", "#donut", "#cool", "#r234", "#FEGERGR", "#fegergr"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a character of any alphabet within hashtag, I'd go with something like this:

```
let text = "улетные #выходные // #holiday in the countryside";
const hashtags = []
if (text.length) {
    let preHashtags = text.split('#')
    let i = 0;
    if (text[0] !== '#') i++ 

    for (null; i < preHashtags.length; i++) {
        let item = preHashtags[i]
        hashtags.push(item.split(' ')[0]) 
        // String.prototype.split() is needed to sort out non-hashtag related string data
    }
}


console.log(hashtags) // outputs [ 'выходные', 'holiday' ]
```

We use `if (text[0] !== '#') i++` to check if first letter in "text" string is not a '#'. In that case we do not need to iterate through the first element in the preHashtags Array. Otherwise, our text string starts with a hashtag and we need to handle it.

Take note that you may need to do input validation of resulting `hashtags` array. Also note that `null` in the for loop is only for readability purposes, you could also use `for (;i < preHashtags.length; i++)`

The benefit of this approach is that it definitely includes any possible symbol (hence the need for sanity checks), including all non-latin alphabets, as well as simpler to understand, especially for beginners. The performance, on the other hand, is superior, when checked in Chrome (and thus probably other Chromium-derived browsers, as well as node.js), while 6-7% worse in Firefox & 13% worse in Safari, judged by this test: https://jsben.ch/VuhEi.

Thus, the choice depends on whether you are going to run your code in node.js or browser and if it is the latter, do you have a lot of mobile clients using MobileSafari?

Answer (score 0):

content.split(/[\s\n\r]/gim).filter(tag => tag.startsWith('#'))