# Regex for Chinese / Japanese letters

Tags: php, regex

Okai so I already have this `regular expression` for names allowed on my website.
However, I also wish to add other possible letters that names use.
Does someone have a good `regex` or know how I can make this more complete? I have searched for quite a while now, and I can't find anything that suits my needs.

This is my current `regex` for checking names:

```
$regex = "/^([a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-])+$/";
if(preg_match($regex, $fullname)){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: you want to match all  ,.'- plus letters ??

Comment: I want to match all letters (that are used in full names) swell as symbols used for full names.

Comment: this is as far as I will go, check this https://regex101.com/r/sR5nO4/2, note  that it appears it cant match the `∂`, but I dont think `∂` and most in your example are chinese(at least I havent seen it myself) nor japanese nor english....

Comment: @Andrew `[a-zA-Z]` is already included in `\p{L}` :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I actually didn't know that, thanks for mentioning :)

Comment: @Andrew Would love if you answered the question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Lucas Trzesniewski has mentioned, the `\p{L}` will include the `[a-zA-Z]`, so I have removed from the pattern.

Thus, combining the character lists that you have included in the example; the pattern will look like this, `/^[\p{L}\s,.'-]+$/u`

`^[]+$` matches the string from start to end, thus `+` also imply the need of matching one or more

`\p{L}` matches unicode characters

`\s,.'-` matches space, comma, period, single quotation, and dash

`u` the `PCRE_UTF8` modifier, this modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl.

```
if(preg_match("/^[\p{L}\s,.'-]+$/u", "お元気ですか你好吗how are you你好嗎,.'-") === 1) {
    echo "match";
}
else {
    echo "no match";
}

// match

if(preg_match("/^[\p{L}\s,.'-]+$/u", "お元気ですか你好吗how are you你好_嗎-,.'") === 1) {
    echo "match";
}
else {
    echo "no match";
}

// no match as there are underscore in 你好_嗎
```