# Detecting String in Specific Format

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was anyway to create a function that 'detects'/finds a string in a specific format.

For example, when the function is run, anything following the format of "#text," where 'text' could be anything, is found and identified. This means thing like "#hash" and "#tag". (This is not limited to hashtags. It could be something like "hello-text" where text could be replaced with anything).

I have done research but failed to find anything useful.

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538860/extracting-hashtags-out-of-a-string

Comment: Ry- Thank you, I will check that out.

Comment: flappix- Thanks, although my inquiry isn't limited to hashtags, I'm sure there is something on there that can help me.